# Is there a way to use the F# interactive mode while debugging a C# program?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

When I'm debugging a C# program in Visual Studio and I've stopped at a breakpoint, is there a way to plug in the F# REPL and evaluate expressions at that scope?

If not, is there any other easy way to evaluate and run arbitrary code while in the middle of a debugging session?

Comment: Roslyn (the new in-developer C# compiler) will have a true C# Interactive like F#, which can do things the Immediate window can't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) for this:

> The **Immediate** window is used to debug and evaluate expressions, execute statements, print variable values, and so forth. It allows you to enter expressions to be evaluated or executed by the development language during debugging. To display the **Immediate** window, open a project for editing, then choose **Windows** from the **Debug** menu and select **Immediate**, or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! Though as for the original question, I guess having full F# is impossible until Roslyn then?

Comment: @JakubArnold Using F# to debug C# is a pretty weird request, the two languages have very different code models. I wouldn't expect to get it from Microsoft. However, I wouldn't say it's impossible--there may be a VS add-in that can do it.